# Reducing one of csv columns contents down single character with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file with headers as follows

```
physicalDeliveryOfficeName,sn,middleName,givenName,info,Company,employeeID,Description
```

And I am wanting to change the contents of the `middleName` column down to just the first character then save it out as another csv file with all of the other columns unchanged.

Im not sure where to start with this.

The csv file is over 12000 rows and Im wanting to do it the most efficient way with powershell.

I am new to using Powershell so advise is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should show some effort. A couple of google searches would go a long way. Here's one way:

```
Import-CSV myfile.csv |
Foreach-Object {
    $_.middleName = $_.middleName.Substring(0,1)
    $_
} |
Select-Object physicalDeliveryOfficeName,sn,middleName,givenName,info,Company,employeeID,Description |
Export-CSV myupdatedfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: If you are starting at 0 isn't is easier to do `$_.middlename = $_.middlename[0]`? Or is that only functional in newer versions of PS?

Comment: As far as I know, it woks in all PS versions. But it includes a "silent cast" to `char[]`. `Substring()` is a documented method for the string-class, so I prefer to use it when explaining to others :) I'd rather have readable code than optimized code unless the question is about speed and performance.